# R - how to drop chars from string depending on their values?

Tags: r, csv, char, numeric, string-parsing

I have a CSV file where numeric values are stored in a way like this:

```
+000000000000000000000001101.7100
```

The number above is 1101.71. This string is always the same length, so number of zeroes before the actual number depends on number´s length.
How can I drop the + and all 0s before the actual number so I can then convert it to numeric easily?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may miss an important point, but my best try would be like this:

1) read the values as a character

2) use substr to get rid of the first character, namely the plus sign

3) convert column with as.integer / this way we safely loose any leading zeroes

Comment: I used in the end a similar solution, more precisely a combination of gsub and as.numeric.

Answer (score 3):

If it is of fixed width, then `substring` will be a faster option

```
as.numeric(substring(str1, nchar(str1)-8))
#[1] 1101.71
```

---

but if we don't know how many 0's will be there at the beginning, then another option is `sub` where we match a `+` at the start (`^`) of the string followed by 0 or more elements of 0 (`0*`) and replace with blank (`""`)

```
as.numeric(sub("^\\+0*", "", str1))
#[1] 1101.71
```

Note that we escape the `+` as it is a metacharacter implying one or more

Comment: I know this method, but with a shorter number it will keep some 0s at the beginning.

Comment: @PrzeM  Updated with another method

Comment: Thanks, but the other reply seemed a bit simpler so used it instead.

Comment: @PrzeM  Isn't that the same thing in description?

Comment: You are right, I might have not noticed the as.numeric function included and though I need another row of code for that.